# Monitor how far the SEQuence has got

Tags: process, pipe, monitoring, seq

I have the following script which has been running for over 3 days:

```
seq -w 1 1000000 | while read i; do (./myscript.pl $i >> output.txt); done
```

Is it possible to find out how far it has got with the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling a command with a different argument for each element, check what argument that command is currently processing.

```
ps w -C myscript.pl
```

You can get an approximate value by checking how many `write` system calls the `seq` process has performed. Find the process ID with `pgrep seq` (or some other command such as `ps uw -C seq` if there are multiple `seq` processes and you need to identify which one you want). If the PID is `1234`, then

```
grep syscw /proc/1234/io
```

reads some IO statistics of the process from [`/proc`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)¹. Add one to this value² then multiply by `getconf PIPE_BUF /`, which is 4096, to get the number of bytes that `seq` has written. This is the total length of all the numbers that it's written so far. Since you're printing constant-width lines, divide by 8 to get the number of numbers written so far.

A more convenient way to see how far `seq` has gone is to [trace its system calls with `strace`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). On Ubuntu, by default, you need to be root to do this.

```
$ strace -p1234
strace: Process 1234 attached
write(1, "0008193\n0008194\n0008195\n0008196\n"..., 4096^Cstrace: Process 1234 detached
```

In the example above, 8193 is the next number that `seq` will write to the pipe, when the reading side has finished processing 8192 and is ready for more.

¹  <sub>If `seq` was writing to a regular file, then `cat /proc/1234/1/fdinfo` or `lsof -p1234` would reveal the offset in the file, which is the number of bytes that `seq` has written. But for a pipe you don't get this information.</sub> 
²  <sub>Determined experimentally. Offhand I don't know why the first write operation writes twice `PIPE_BUF`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your script does, but could you `watch cat output.txt` in another terminal to monitor what your output file looks like?

Alternatively (and I know this isn't what you're asking for) perhaps run your command like this:

`seq -w 1 1000000 | while read i; do (./myscript.pl $i >> output.txt & echo i); done`

or

`seq -w 1 1000000 | while read i; do (./myscript.pl $i tee -a output.txt); done`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`pv`** pipe view util](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):

```
seq -w 1 1000000 | pv -lcs 1M | 
while read i; do (./myscript.pl $i >> output.txt); done
```

...which will output to *STDERR* a constantly updated progress bar giving both the number of lines read, and the percentage of lines done at the moment.